# How would I create a silverlight control for tagging content similar to StackOverflow?

Tags: silverlight

I am new to Silverlight.  How would I go about creating a control for users to tag content.

I would like it to work like it does it StackOverflow i.e. Autocomplete and when you press space it inserts the tag in a box with a remove button.  I want the control to be bindable to a collection of strings.

If someone can just point me in the right direction to get me started I would be very grateful.

Comment: Depends whether you see wanting to create a control for all this, or just a UserControl for a specific application... either way items controls and data templates would be a good place to start using.

Comment: OK so I use an ItemsControl bound to the string collection to create the readonly tags with a remove button.  How do I combine this with an autocomplete textbox when the user clicks to the right of the tags.  How do I get it so when the user leaves the autocomplete box it updates the string collection?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with an AutoComplete Textbox, there is already one available in the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Wikipage). Tim Heuer has several examples using it (he actually creates one himself in one of his posts somewhere), you can find one [sample here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/11/03/silverlight-autocompletebox-with-custom-data-types.aspx). Once you have this in place, the rest of the control is pretty simple.